# Update SQL Table not working

Tags: vba, excel

I am not sure why vba to update changes to sql table is not working.I have a button at the top of my spreadsheet to update records.

The stored procedure is updating. But when done through excel, it does not take in the update.Please review.

```
Sub Employee_Button2_Click()
    Dim sBackupUpdQry As String
    Dim sUpdQry As String
    Dim iRows As Integer
    Dim qryUpdateArray(4000) As String
    Dim iCols As Integer

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler


    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim lLastCol As Integer

    lLastRow = Cells.Find("*", Range("A3"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row ' Find the last row with data
    lLastCol = Cells.Find("*", Range("A3"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column ' Find the last column with data


    Dim iRecCount As Integer

    With Sheets("Select and Update Employee")

        sBackupUpdQry = "EXEC usp_UpdateEmployee_FTE"


        iRows = 3
        iRecCount = 1

        For iRecCount = 1 To lLastRow - 3

            iRows = iRows + 1
            sUpdQry = ""



            sUpdQry = sUpdQry + " , @GroupingParm = '" + CStr(Cells(iRows, 3)) + "'"
            sUpdQry = sUpdQry + " , @CCNumParm = '" + CStr(Cells(iRows, 4)) + "'"
            sUpdQry = sUpdQry + " , @CCNameParm = '" + CStr(Cells(iRows, 5)) + "'"
            sUpdQry = sUpdQry + " , @ResTypeNumParm = '" + CStr(Cells(iRows, 6)) + "'"
            sUpdQry = sUpdQry + " , @ResNameParm = '" + CStr(Cells(iRows, 7)) + "'"
            sUpdQry = sUpdQry + " , @StatusParm = '" + CStr(Cells(iRows, 8)) + "'"


            sUpdQry = sBackupUpdQry + " @EmpIDParm = '" + CStr(Cells(iRows, 1)) + "' " + " , @ENameParm = '" + CStr(Cells(iRows, 2)) + "' " + sUpdQry

            qryUpdateArray(iRecCount) = sUpdQry

'oConn.Execute qryUpdateArray(iRecCount)
            Next iRecCount



        End With


        Call DBConnection.OpenDBConnection

        Dim rsMY_Resources As ADODB.Recordset
        Set rsMY_Resources = New ADODB.Recordset


        Dim cntUpd As Integer
        cntUpd = 0

        For iRecCount = 1 To lLastRow - 3

            If qryUpdateArray(iRecCount) > "" Then

                oConn.Execute qryUpdateArray(iRecCount)
                cntUpd = cntUpd + 1
            End If

            Next iRecCount

            Call DBConnection.CloseDBConnection
            MsgBox ("Employee_FTE has been updated")

            Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
            MsgBox (Error)


End Sub
```

Comment: Change `>` to `<>` in `If qryUpdateArray(iRecCount) > "" Then`. After this line, insert `debug.print qryUpdateArray(iRecCount)`. Update your question with the output (some of them).

Comment: Also add some `Debug.Print qryUpdateArray(iRecCount)` before `oConn.Execute qryUpdateArray(iRecCount)` ans ee if it is valid in the immediate window. Post the first of them here if you have doubts.

Comment: At a guess.. when you transfer a value from excel to your SP parameters it makes the value slightly different and it no longer matches a record to be updated. I suggest that firstly you remove `On Error Goto` altogether. If you are having issues this can sometimes hide things. When you get it working you can put it back in. Anyway, you basically need to step through your code and pay close attention to the parameter values (is there an extra space, a comma, or a unneeded quote?).